# admin aoolbar add_node() and pulling in my post slug

Tags: customization, admin-menu

I have created custom post types that use custom endpoints to load the correct template based upon the content the user is viewing.

I created custom Admin Toolbar menu items.

```
  $wp_adminbar->add_node([
    'id' => 'svcta-view-directory-hotel',
    'title' => 'Launch Hotel View',
    'href' => home_url('/directory/hotels/SLUG/stay'),
    'meta' => [ 'target' => 'blank' ]
  ]);
```

In home_url('/directory/hotels/SLUG/stay') – How can I pull the slug of the current custom post type entry being edited?

For example, when I edit this entry: http://svcta.lainternet.biz/directory/micah-test-all/stay/

The standard “View Listing” link goes to http://svcta.lainternet.biz/directory/micah-test-all/ - This is broken because it doesn’t load the custom endpoint “/stay/”.

I need a new custom link that will open a new tab and show this Custom Post Type entry on the correct 
“/stay/” endpoint.

I searched for a few hours and couldn’t find any solutions.

Thanks for the help!

Micah

Answer (score 0):

if you want to customise the links in the backend list, you can use this filter :

```
add_filter("post_row_actions", function ($actions, \WP_Post $post) {

    if ("custom_post_type_slug" === $post->post_type) {

        // modify a existing action or add a new in $actions

        $actions["other link"] = "<a href=\"url\">other link</a>";

    }

    return $actions;

}, 10, 2);
```